# MATLAB - Adaptive Step Size Runge-Kutta

Tags: matlab, error-handling, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I've programmed in MATLAB an adaptive step size RK4 to solve a system of ODEs. The code runs without error, however it does not produce the desired curve when I try to plot x against y. Instead of being a toroidal shape, I simply get a flat line. This is evident from the fact that r is outputting a constant value. After checking the outputs of each line, they are not outputting constants or errors or inf or NaN, rather they are outputting both a real and imaginary component (complex numbers). I have no idea as to why this is occurring and I believe it to be the source of my trouble.

```
function AdaptRK4()
parsec  = 3.08*10^18;
r_1     = 8.5*1000.0*parsec; % in cm
theta_1 = 0.0;
a       = 0.5*r_1;
gam     = 1;

grav    = 6.6720*10^-8;
amsun   = 1.989*10^33;
amg     = 1.5d11*amsun;   
gm      = grav*amg;    

u_1     = 20.0*10^5; 
v       = sqrt(gm/r_1); 

time    = 0.0;
epsilon = 0.00001;
m1      = 0.5;
m2      = 0.5;
m3      = 0.5;
i       = 1;
nsteps  = 50000;
deltat  = 5.0*10^12; 

angmom  = r_1*v;
angmom2 = angmom^2.0;
e       = -2*10^5.0*gm/r_1+u_1*u_1/2.0+angmom2/(2.0*r_1*r_1);

for i=1:nsteps
deltat  = min(deltat,nsteps-time);

fk3_1   = deltat*u_1;
fk4_1   = deltat*(-gm*r_1*r_1^(-gam)/(a+r_1)^(3-    gam)+angmom2/(r_1^3.0)); 
fk5_1   = deltat*(angmom/(r_1^2.0));
r_2     = r_1+fk3_1/4.0;
u_2     = u_1+fk4_1/4.0;
theta_2 = theta_1+fk5_1/4.0;

fk3_2   = deltat*u_2;
fk4_2   = deltat*(-gm*r_2*r_2^(-gam)/(a+r_2)^(3-gam)+angmom2/(r_2^3.0)); 
fk5_2   = deltat*(angmom/(r_2^2.0));        
r_3     = r_1+(3/32)*fk3_1 + (9/32)*fk3_2;
u_3     = u_1+(3/32)*fk4_1 + (9/32)*fk4_2;
theta_3 = theta_1+(3/32)*fk5_1 + (9/32)*fk5_2;

fk3_3   = deltat*u_3;                        
fk4_3   = deltat*(-gm*r_3*r_3^(-gam)/(a+r_3)^(3-gam)+angmom2/(r_3^3.0));
fk5_3   = deltat*(angmom/(r_3^2.0));            
r_4     = r_1+(1932/2197)*fk3_1 - (7200/2197)*fk3_2 + (7296/2197)*fk3_3;
u_4     = u_1+(1932/2197)*fk4_1 - (7200/2197)*fk4_2 + (7296/2197)*fk4_3;
theta_4 = theta_1+(1932/2197)*fk5_1 - (7200/2197)*fk5_2 + (7296/2197)*fk5_3;

fk3_4   = deltat*u_4;                        
fk4_4   = deltat*(-gm*r_4*r_4^(-gam)/(a+r_4)^(3-gam)+angmom2/(r_4^3.0));
fk5_4   = deltat*(angmom/(r_4^2.0));            
r_5     = r_1+(439/216)*fk3_1 - 8*fk3_2 + (3680/513)*fk3_3 -     (845/4104)*fk3_4;
u_5     = u_1+(439/216)*fk4_1 - 8*fk4_2 + (3680/513)*fk4_3 - (845/4104)*fk4_4;
theta_5 = theta_1+(439/216)*fk5_1 - 8*fk5_2 + (3680/513)*fk5_3 -     (845/4104)*fk5_4;

fk3_5   = deltat*u_5;                        
fk4_5   = deltat*(-gm*r_5*r_5^(-gam)/(a+r_5)^(3-gam)+angmom2/(r_5^3.0));
fk5_5   = deltat*(angmom/(r_5^2.0));            
r_6     = r_1-(8/27)*fk3_1 - 2*fk3_2 - (3544/2565)*fk3_3 + (1859/4104)*fk3_4-(11/40)*fk3_5;
u_6     = u_1-(8/27)*fk4_1 - 2*fk4_2 - (3544/2565)*fk4_3 + (1859/4104)*fk4_4-(11/40)*fk4_5;
theta_6 = theta_1-(8/27)*fk5_1 - 2*fk5_2 - (3544/2565)*fk5_3 + (1859/4104)*fk5_4-(11/40)*fk5_5;

fk3_6   = deltat*u_6;          
fk4_6   = deltat*(-gm*r_6*r_6^(-gam)/(a+r_6)^(3-gam)+angmom2/(r_6^3.0)); 
fk5_6   = deltat*(angmom/(r_6^2.0)); 

fm3_1 = m1 + 25*fk3_1/216+1408*fk3_3/2565+2197*fk3_4/4104-fk3_5/5;
fm4_1 = m2 + 25*fk4_1/216+1408*fk4_3/2565+2197*fk4_4/4104-fk4_5/5;
fm5_1 = m3 + 25*fk5_1/216+1408*fk5_3/2565+2197*fk5_4/4104-fk5_5/5;
fm3_2 = m1 + 16*fk3_1/135+6656*fk3_3/12825+28561*fk3_4/56430-9*fk3_5/50+2*fk3_6/55;
fm4_2 = m2 + 16*fk4_1/135+6656*fk4_3/12825+28561*fk4_4/56430-9*fk4_5/50+2*fk4_6/55;
fm5_2 = m3 + 16*fk5_1/135+6656*fk5_3/12825+28561*fk5_4/56430-9*fk5_5/50+2*fk5_6/55;
R3    = abs(fm3_1-fm3_2)/deltat;
R4    = abs(fm4_1-fm4_2)/deltat;
R5    = abs(fm5_1-fm5_2)/deltat;
err3 = 0.84*(epsilon/R3)^(1/4);
err4 = 0.84*(epsilon/R4)^(1/4);
err5 = 0.84*(epsilon/R5)^(1/4);


if  R3<= epsilon
    time = time+deltat;
    fm3 = fm3_1;
    i = i+1;
    deltat = err3*deltat;
end

if  R4<= epsilon
    time = time+deltat;
    fm4 = fm4_1;
    i = i+1;
    deltat = err4*deltat;  
end

if  R5<= epsilon
    time = time+deltat;
    fm5 = fm5_1;
    i = i+1;
    deltat = err5*deltat;   
end

e=2*gm^2.0/(2*angmom2);  
ecc=(1.0+(2.0*e*angmom2)/(gm^2.0))^0.5; 
x(i)=r_1*cos(theta_1)/(1000.0*parsec); 
y(i)=r_1*sin(theta_1)/(1000.0*parsec); 
time=time+deltat;
r(i)=r_1;
time1(i)=time;   
end

figure()
plot(x,y, '-k');
TeXString = title('Plot of Orbit in Gamma Potential Obtained Using     RK4')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting complex values because at some point `npts - time < 0`.  You may want to print out the values of `deltat` to check the error.

Also, your code doesn't seem to take into account the case when the error estimate is larger than your tolerance.  When your error estimate is greater than your tolerance you have to:

1. Shift back the time AND solution
2. calculate a new step-size based on a formula, and
3. recalculate your solution and error estimate.

The fact that you don't know how many iterations you will have to go through makes the use of a for-loop for adaptive runge Kutta a bit awkward.  I suggest using a while loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "i" in your code. "i" returns the basic imaginary unit. "i" is equivalent to sqrt(-1). Try to use another identifier in your loops and only use "i" or "j" in calculations where complex numbers are involved.

Comment: I changed all instances of i to k, nothing changed.